# Trying to solve wave equation with initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

> Solve the initial value problem:
> $$
> u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0 \\
> u(x,0) = 0 \\
> u_t(x,0) = \begin{cases} \cos \pi (x-1) & \text{if } 1 < x < 2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
> $$
> Find and draw the solution at $t=3$ for
>
> (a). $x\in (-\infty, \infty)$.
>
> (b). $x\in (0, \infty)$ with $u_x(0,t) = 0$.
>
> (c). $x\in (-\infty, 3)$ with $u(3,t) = 0$.
>
> (d). $x\in (0,3)$ with $u_x(0,t)=u_x(3,t)=0$.

For (a) since we are in the entire real line, we can just use d'Alembert's solution and obtain $u = \sin(\pi(x-3t))-\sin(\pi(x+3t))$, but how do we do it for the other cases that we have semi infinite domain?

For (d) we can use separation of variables, correct?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only ask questions about a single problem. This is not the place for a homework dump.

With that being said, I'm going to solve the first problem. First, define the primitive of $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$ as

$$ G(s) = \int g(s)\ ds = \begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{\pi}\sin\big(\pi(s-1)\big), & 1 < s < 2 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Then the solution given by d'Alembert's formula is

$$ u(x,t) = \frac{G(x+t) - G(x-t)}{2} $$

where you have to check case by case for both $x+t$ and $x-t$. Below is a graph ($x$ vs. $t$) of the 4 characteristic lines going through $x=1$ and $x=2$.

[image]

The numbered regions are as follows:

\begin{array}{rrr}
\text{I}: && x - t < 1, && x + t < 1 \\
\text{II}: && x - t < 1, && 1 < x + t < 2 \\
\text{III}: && x - 1 < 1, && x + t > 2 \\
\text{IV}: && 1 < x - t < 2, && 1 < x + t < 2 \\
\text{V}: && 1 < x - t < 2, && x + t > 2 \\
\text{VI}: && x - t > 2, && x + t > 2 \\
\end{array}
Then, you can simplify the solution

$$ u(x,t) = \begin{cases} 
0, && (x,t) \in \text{I, III, VI} \\ 
\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\sin\big(\pi(x+t-1)\big), && (x,t) \in \text{II} \\
\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\Big[\sin\big(\pi(x+t-1)\big) - \sin\big(\pi(x-t-1)\big) \Big], && (x,t) \in \text{IV} \\
-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\sin\big(\pi(x-t-1)\big), && (x,t) \in \text{V}
\end{cases} $$

Comment: can you give a hint in to how to approach part b) ?

Comment: @MikeySpivak I commented on your other question. (b) is an even extension (of the above free-space solution) across $x=0$. (c) is an odd extension across $x=3$. For (d) separation of variables will do the trick.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @MikeySpivak The solution for (b) is given by $v(x,t) = u(x,t) + u(-x,t)$ where $u(x,t)$ is the solution in (a). Similarly, the solution is (c) is given by $v(x,t) = u(x,t) - u(6-x,t)$

Comment: how do you get part (c)?

Comment: @MikeySpivak $u(6-x,t)$ is the reflection of $u(x,t)$ across the line $x=3$. As you know, the second derivative operator is shift invariant, so the second term also satisfies the wave equation

Comment: thank you very much