# Finding initial conditions of 1-D Wave Equation PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

I am trying to solve a 1-D wave equation PDE. My first step was to find all the initial conditions I could which is proving more difficult than I thought. The problem is below.

[image]

The initial conditions I found were:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(-\infty - 12 , 0) = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(12 - 17, 0) = \frac{8}{5}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(17 - 22, 0) = -\frac{8}{5}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(22 - \infty, 0) = 0$$

Are these correct/are there anymore I have missed? And how would I use this in an equation since they all are within a "range", can I just pick any $x$ value between $12$ and $17$ and write the derivative at that point is $\frac{8}{5}$ and use it to find a particular solution?

example: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(13, 0) = \frac{8}{5}$$

Comment: You need to make a case distinction within d'Alamberts formula. Then, you can quote easily construct the right region. Besides, you will need a different way tot write the conditions down, like $u(x,t)=0$ for $x\leq 12$ etc. Does this help? If not, let me know and I could write a more complete solution

Comment: Try to solve the equation in each of the 4 different cases of initial conditions. Then you have solutions for all 4 regions, which you can then combine to form a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the entire function at $t=0$, not just the slopes.

The initial condition is piece-wise linear and has this general form

$$ u(x,0) = A(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 12 \\ ax + b, & 12 < x < 17 \\ cx + d, & 17 < x < 22 \\ 0, &  x > 22 \end{cases} $$

You can find the constants $a,b,c,d$ using the given function values at $x=12,17,22$

In fact, you've already determined that $a=8/5$ and $c=-8/5$

Comment: Thanks for the help Dylan, would you think it's reasonable to assume that if $A(x)$ represented say a string that it is tied to $0$ at $x = 12$ and $x = 22$? For example $u(12, t) = 0$ and $u(22, t) = 0$.

Comment: Also in your answer did you mean $u(x, 0) = A(x)$?

Comment: @Asyu7 No, the domain is free space, so cannot assume any points are fixed, unless specified in the problem. Just use d'Alembert's formula

Comment: Okay, I will look into it thank you.

Comment: Hi Dylan I have been looking into D'Alemberts formula for a while now and am still really struggling. Would you mind, if you are able to. Going into more detail on how I could solve this problem?

Comment: @Asyu7 The answer given by d'Alembert is simply $$u(x,t) = \frac{A(x+ct) + A(x-ct)}{2}$$ where $A(x)=u(x,0)$ and $c=1/5$. If you want to know to full form, that's bit more complicated and requires checking cases. I answered a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3181945/135643)